# Data value not showing up from JSON file at html page after submitting form

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, axios

Hi everyone out there I require some assistance about Axios & VUE after submitting a form in my webpage i was redirected back to this page. Before the form was submitted the "purposeofvisit" was not empty at the html file but after submitting the form and redirected back to the html page It is empty. I am trying to access the nested object "purposeofvisit" value

```
let patients = new Vue({
  el: "#patients",
  data: {
    patients: [],
  },

  mounted: function () {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/patients")
      .then((response) => {
        

        userParticulars = response.data;

        this.patients = userParticulars;

        console.log(this.purposeofvisit);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
 
});
```

```
<tbody v-for="(user, index) in patients" :key="index">
  <tr>
  <td>{{user.appointments[0].purposeofvisit}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is the JSON file i am accessing

```
{
  "patients": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John", 
      ],
      "appointments": [
        
          {
            "purposeofvisit": "Consultation",       
          }
        
      ]
}
```

Comment: Might need to edit depending on if you are doing columns or rows but something like this work. You can v-for over the appointments. `<tr v-for="(appt, index) in user.appointments" :key="index"><td>{{ purposeofvisit }}</td></tr>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thee appointments has nested arrays. You could try accessing nested arrays.

```js
user.appointments[0][0].purposeofvisit
```

Comment: Hi thanks sir its not the answer im looking for but after you mentioning its a "nested array" i went to check. The error actually occurs in my other Javascript files . Thanks again